# How to Send Hazelcast map statistics to datadog using micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, datadog, micrometer

I'm implementing Hazelcast caching in my service using Spring boot cache and I want to send hit and miss metrics to my Datadog.

I tried to enable statistics and JMX but it didn't work.

my `hazelcast.yaml`:

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: false
#        change these 2 lines and set kubernetes enabled to false for local debug
#        enabled: true
#        members: 127.0.0.1
      kubernetes:
        enabled: true
        namespace: my-namespace
        service-name: my-service
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    jmx:
      enabled: true
  map:
    default:
      statistics-enabled: true
      time-to-live-seconds: 86400
      eviction:
        max-size-policy: PER_NODE
        eviction-policy: LFU
        size: 200000
```

application.yaml:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
  metrics:
    export:
      statsd:
        enabled: true
        flavor: datadog
        port: 8125
        host: ${HOST_IP}
```

The cache is working properly, and other metrics are being sent to datadog as expected

I Then found that there is a way to add a custom listener for example [EntryListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.2.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/EntryListener.html) but I'm not sure how to utilize it to send hit and miss since it listens on added, update, removed, evicted, expired and cleared events
so added probably can be utilized to send miss event, but what about update?

My last resort is to create a sync method that send periodically map metrics to DD which I really want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for that -
Micrometer provides `HazelcastCacheMetrics` that let's you monitor Hazelcast caches to a `MeterRegistry` in the following way:

```java
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.ImmutableTag;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.cache.HazelcastCacheMetrics;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.List;


@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HazelcastMetricBinder {
    public static String My_CACHE_NAME = "MyCacheName";
    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    private final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    @PostConstruct
    void monitorHazelcastCacheMetrics() {
        List<Tag> tags = List.of(new ImmutableTag("cacheName", My_CACHE_NAME));
        HazelcastCacheMetrics.monitor(meterRegistry, hazelcastInstance.getMap(My_CACHE_NAME), tags);
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi: you can also do `Tags.of("cacheName", "MyCacheName")`